# Edit my website with cURL

Tags: wordpress, curl, web

I want to make my website automatic that it means to get data from other websites using cURL. I have a news portal : lajm-shqip.com. Can you help me with some specific advice how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a php file somewhere, that get the page you want using cUrl (see php man).

Then, on your website, make an ajax request on that php file whenever you need to get the content.
Just add what your ajax request gave you in a div (using jquery or the whatever).